# Full width Div Background

Tags: css

So, I've got this:

```
.container_2{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1900px;
  color: white;
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/RyxFhXn/aldebaran-s-O-6kqn-Ev-O1s-unsplash.jpg');

}
```

but the bg-image is not full width, its
[multiplying itself to cover the width required, rather than](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGnOs.png)  covering full div container, without requiring it to multiply.

Comment: hello, can you share the html?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container_2{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1900px;
  color: white;
   background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/RyxFhXn/aldebaran-s-O-6kqn-Ev-O1s-unsplash.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_2">

</div>
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Yep! Thanks a lot.